# How do I change the colour of all markers on a map at the same time in android? How do I only change the colour of some of the markers?

Tags: java, android, google-maps-markers, marker

Situation 1:
Say I populate a map with blue markers as such:

```
for (LatLng latLng : latLngList) {
  mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
}
```

On clicking a marker, I wish to change the colour of every marker on the map to yellow. How would I do this?

Currently, I can only manage to change the colour of the specific marker that I click on using this method:

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
  //change marker colour to yellow
  marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW));


  return false;
}
```

Situation 2:
Say I have 2 kinds of markers, blue and red, created from two different lists of latLngs.

```
//create blue markers
for (LatLng latLng : latLngListBlue) {
  mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
}

//create red markers
for (LatLng latLng : latLngListRed) {
  mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
 }
```

On clicking a *red* marker, I want all *blue* markers to change to yellow. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to your markers and then modify them when you want.

```
List<Marker> mMarkers = new Arraylist<Marker>();

for (LatLng latLng : latLngList) {
        Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
        mMarkers.add(marker);
}
```

and then

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    //change marker colour to yellow
    marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW));
    for(Marker otherMarker : mMarkers) {
        otherMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW));
    }

    return false;
}
```

similar workaround for the second situation

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. 
Also I assume by List<LatLng> mMarkers you mean List<Marker> mMarkers.

Comment: glad to help! your assumption was about list type was right, corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by saving a list for all of the markers with an id for the color. You can use List with a POJO with Marker and the Id like this:

```
public class MarkerWithColor {
  private Marker marker;
  private int colorId; // red = 0, green = 1, blue = 2

  public MarkerWithColor(Marker marker, int colorId) {
    this.marker = marker;
    this.colorId = colorId;
  }
  // getter
  // setter 
}
```

Then, each time you adding the marker, create the pojo and save to the list:

```
List<MarkerWithColor> markerWithColors = new ArrayList<>();

// adding blue marker
for (LatLng latLng : latLngList) {
  Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
  // add to the list
  markerWithColors.add(new MarkerWithColor(marker, 2)); // 2 is blue color
}

/* Do the same for the red and green */

// Now you can change the specific color
// Change blue to yellow
for(int i = 0; i < markerWithColors.size(); i++) {
  MarkerWithColor markerWithColor = markerWithColors.get(i);
  markerWithColor.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW));
}
```

You can also use **Enum** instead of **int** for the colorId. And you can also use [Pair](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html) instead of the POJO.